# Memory Error in Android Button creation with sound

Tags: android, media-player

I am making an app now that plays sounds according to which button i press , problem is I got like 100 buttons and 100 different sounds and after a while It rapes the memory and it crashes giving me the (-19,0) error here is my code , can u tell me how I can avoid that?? thanks

```
 package com.example.buttonsdemo;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

        //Creating Sound arrays 
        MediaPlayer[] mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer[200];
        int i = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            //Creating Button Array
            Button button[] = new Button [200]; 
            mediaplayer[1]= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alistar);
            mediaplayer[0]= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.akali);






            button[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch(v.getId())
                    {

                case R.id.akali:
                                        i=0;
                    break;
                case R.id.alistar:
                    i=1;
                    break;
                            }
mediaplayer[1].start(); 
                }
            } );








    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }




    }
```

Edit: I tried to make it more generic so I call only 1 .start();

Comment: `MediaPlayer[] mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer[200];`  Wow, just wow.  Why not use one and reassign the sound to play.  Or use SoundPool.

Comment: what is SoundPool and what is the difference ??

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you should probably be using an Android `ListView` for your click targets instead of a giant `Array` of `Buttons` to click on.  This will save you a lot of memory.  Second, you should use something like a soundPool instead of a big collection of MediaPlayers.  If that route doesn't look attractive for you, you'll need to create a MediaPlayer for each click and then throw it away.  A simple solution along those lines would look like this:

Main class:

```
class MyActivity {
  private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
  private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundMap;
  private ListView mListView;
  private ArrayAdapter<Integer> mAdapter;

  @Override
  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAdapter = new MySimpleSoundAdapter();

    int[] sounds = {R.raw.alistar, R.raw.alkili, /*...*/ };

    mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.textview, sounds));
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        MediaPlayer mp = 
            MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, (int) mAdapter.getItem(position);
        mp.start(); 
      }
    });
  }
}
```